# Can't assign value of type Dictionary to LazyMapCollection

Tags: swift

I am working on an application and I am relatively new to Swift where I am trying to initialize answerKeys with the keys of answer variable with the following code but it is showing an error.

> Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<IntPoint, String>.Keys' to type 'LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<IntPoint, String>, IntPoint>' (aka 'LazyMapSequence<Dictionary<IntPoint, String>, IntPoint>')

I have gone through the documentation but couldn't fix this.

```
var answer:[IntPoint:String] = [:]
var answerKeys:LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<IntPoint,String>,IntPoint>

init() {
    answerKeys = answer.keys
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that `Dictionary.keys` returned a `LazyMapCollection` in earlier Swift versions. In Swift 5 it is `Dictionary<Key, Value>.Keys` as can be seen from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894263-keys), in your case

```
var answerKeys: Dictionary<IntPoint, String>.Keys
```

But note that you can always access `answer.keys` in your code instead of assigning this to a separate property.